# Race condition in Google Sheets API

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I am using pygsheets to update and delete data in a Google Sheet. The data is refreshed by using the `append_table` function to delete the old data and insert the new data.

Is it possible that two user make the same request at the same time, resulting in a combination of both requests? Or will the API first protect the work sheet and then perform CURD operations on the last request.

Below is my command:

```
worksheet.append_table(values=sheet_rows, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [append_table](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/blob/844a00bf25a232f4c76189be84a59d92c3408b58/pygsheets/sheet.py#L201) source code for pygsheets and the underlying API method ([spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)) being used in the Google Sheets API call, it looks like the last request made would overwrite the first request made.

This is because pygsheets is passing the `spreadsheets.values.append` command to the Google API, which will process it as a single request with the [InsertDataOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#InsertDataOption) to overwrite the old data in one step (not two steps of deleting then inserting).

I hope that helps.